# Need help making an iteration for hangman game

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make a hangman game, and I need to make when I create hangman (using images) into a 'for' loop instead of running one by one sorted by current_attempts of player. How would I do this?

Code:

```py
def draw_hangman(current_attempts):
   if current_attempts == 0:
       window.blit(HeadScale, (575,115))
   elif current_attempts == 1:
       window.blit(bodyScale, (575,180))
       window.blit(HeadScale, (575,115))
   elif current_attempts == 2:
       window.blit(bodyScale, (575,180))
       window.blit(HeadScale, (575,115))
       window.blit(rightarmScale, (600,180))
   elif current_attempts == 3:
       window.blit(bodyScale, (575,180))
       window.blit(HeadScale, (575,115))
       window.blit(rightarmScale, (600,180))
       window.blit(leftarmScale, (540,190))
   elif current_attempts == 4:
       window.blit(bodyScale, (575,180))
       window.blit(HeadScale, (575,115))
       window.blit(rightarmScale, (600,180))
       window.blit(leftarmScale, (540,190))
       window.blit(leftlegScale, (540,280))
   elif current_attempts == 5:
       window.blit(bodyScale, (575,180))
       window.blit(HeadScale, (575,115))
       window.blit(rightarmScale, (600,180))
       window.blit(leftarmScale, (540,190))
       window.blit(leftlegScale, (540,280))
       window.blit(rightlegScale, (570,280))
```

Im just trying to fix this and make it into a simple for loop but not sure how.

I have no clue how to do it. I was thinking like "for x in range(0, current attempts)" but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Do you really need to blit all the previous body parts again? The head is already showing, just add the body to it on the next attempt, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the blitting parameters in a list. Slice it based on the current attempt number, and then loop over that.

```
def draw_hangman(current_attempt):
    parts = [
        (HeadScale, (575, 115)),
        (bodyScale, (575,180)),
        (rightarmScale, (600,180)),
        (leftarmScale, (540,190)),
        (leftlegScale, (540,280)),
        (rightlegScale, (570,280))
    ]
    for part in parts[0:current_attempt+1]:
        window.blit(*part)
```